# npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, fsevents

I'm trying to run [this project](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app).
After updating `minimatch` version to 3.10.9, I'm getting the following error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
```

My configuration:

```
Node v - 4.4.2
npm v - 3.10.9
32 bit windows OS
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like an error to me - are you having trouble running the code despite this? `npm WARN` is just that - a warning that might be worth paying attention to, but didn't actually break anything.

Comment: And this particular warning is just telling you that an optional dependency did not install because your platform didn't match it's requirements.  In this case it's looking for [darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) and you are on win32

Comment: its a grunt project, after running this command "npm install -g grunt-cli", i try to run npm install when i get this warning,

Comment: @AishwaryTiwari, did you actually get an error, or does the code not work? Warnings are unlikely to be an actual problem, because (as the error message says), it skipped an optional dependency.

Comment: There is a pull request that fixes the problem: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/19198 You can subscribe to that pull request, so you get an update when it will be closed.

Comment: Simply add `"optionalDependencies": { "fsevents": "*" }` to the package.json file, then use  `--no-optional` flag like `npm install --no-optional`.

Comment: This sure is a lot of people accepting warnings, as if they aren't, what's the word... warning you of a problem.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error. It occurs because `fsevents` is an optional dependency, used only when project is run on macOS environment (the package provides 'Native Access to Mac OS-X FSEvents').

And since you're running your project on Windows, `fsevents` is skipped as irrelevant.

There is a PR to fix this behaviour here: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/169

Comment: Isn't something that is optional and is dependent contradicting itself?

Comment: That is more of a theoretical question. Maybe `conditional dependency` would be better? Naming is hard. I guess it was not easy to find a good name for this case while keeping it concise.

Comment: Absolutely. Hardest thing in SW Development. But if it was a conditional dependency, it would be logical that if the condition was not met, it would not generate the warning as it does now.

Comment: npm install --no-optional

Comment: _"It's only a warning"_ creates a culture of risky complacency.  I've witnessed serious production bugs that directly resulted from continually ignoring warnings.

Comment: I totally agree, @DemPilafian. Thus I edited my original response and removed "only". I personally treat warnings like errors, but in this case, IMHO, this should not be logged as a warning, but rather info, as in Windows environment you cannot do anything to make the warning go away.

Comment: Good answer, now how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Really annoying. That makes every developer on Windows question their code or settings. Why should do I care Mac-OS warnings when I code on Windows. It's a development dependencies (?), not a runtime dependency.

Comment: npm install --no-optional by @suiwenfeng works like a charm. Thanks,

Comment: @TetraDev use yarn instead (or use a Mac I guess.)

Comment: npm cli devs claim this been fixed in NPM v7: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/169

Comment: Just be aware that npm@7 is still in beta.

Answer (score 39):

This still appears to be an issue, causing package installations to be aborted with warnings about optional packages not being installed because of "Unsupported platform".

The problem relates to the "shrinkwrap" or `package-lock.json` which gets persisted after every package manager execution. Subsequent attempts keep failing as this file is referenced instead of `package.json`.

Adding these options to the `npm install` command should allow packages to install again.

```
   --no-optional argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.

   --no-shrinkwrap argument, which will ignore an available package lock or
                   shrinkwrap file and use the package.json instead.

   --no-package-lock argument will prevent npm from creating a package-lock.json file.
```

The complete command looks like this:

```
    npm install --no-optional --no-shrinkwrap --no-package-lock
```

nJoy!

Comment: Is it risky to set the `--no-optional`-flag for code that works just to get rid of the warning? Why is it not set by default?

Comment: This cannot be a solution since using package-lock.json is a good thing and this solution suggests the opposite.

Comment: @ismailarilik This solution allows me to install packages so that I can go on with my work.

Comment: "--no-optional" is a really, really Bad Idea.  It's usually OK to ignore the warning.  You can also use `npm install -f`: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935

Answer (score 28):

Using parameter --force:

```
npm i -f
```

Comment: I did force the installation once with this command and now when I launch `npm install` I do not have any warnings thanks !

Comment: I got some errors while running that command, but after re-running npm install the warnings were gone! thank you sir

Comment: So you're installing in your project those useless dependencies (in a windows machine) to get out the warnings? If so, I hope tree-shaking getting rid of them at production building. I like the workaround. It gets rid of apple-related stuff on my screen.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Run with force once and it's fixed forever

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178041/2230325) worked for me, add this to your `package.json`

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
}
```

Comment: I tried this: I still get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

> Unsupported platform for fsevents

The current best solution is [upgrading your version of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm), which won't have this warning.

If using a Windows machine, an easy way to upgrade is with the tool [Upgrade npm on Windows](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade).