# Trying to install vue js in windows 8.1?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am trying to install Vue.js through the command prompt on Windows 8.1.

I have installed Node.js successfully, but when I try to install Vue.js, I get this error:

```
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
})
```

Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: This isn't an error, it's a warning stating that the dependency `fsevents` is being ignored since you're not on MacOS (rightfully so - the FSEvents API is native to the Cocoa API, which is Mac only). You should be able to safely ignore it.

Comment: This warning has no side-effects, have been using vue-cli for over 3 months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226745/npm-warn-notsup-skipping-optional-dependency-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents)

Comment: this fsevents thing always bother windows users just ignore it.