# fsevents error on angular with springboot application

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring-boot, npm-install

I am trying to create a angular sample with springboot application. When I tried to install bootstrapt, I got this error. ng version and npm version are in below.

How do I implement these ui components?

```
C:\workspace\ng2boot\src\main\webapp\angular2>npm install bootstrap@3
angular2@0.0.0 C:\workspace\ng2boot\src\main\webapp\angular2
`-- bootstrap@3.3.7

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})



C:\workspace\ng2boot\src\main\webapp\angular2>ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 6.11.1
os: win32 x64


C:\workspace\ng2boot\src\main\webapp\angular2>npm -v
3.10.10
```

Comment: It is not error it is warning, angular should still work

Comment: I know but I want to implement these ui components. How can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226745/npm-warn-notsup-skipping-optional-dependency-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents)

Comment: have you tried after clearing cache like this `npm cache clean` ?

Comment: I tried clean cache, angular2@0.0.0 C:\workspace\ng2boot\src\main\webapp\angular2
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.3.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fsevents is a development-time 'file watcher' library that is only needed/available for Mac OS X.

Since you are on Windows, the OPTIONAL dependency cannot be satisfied (nor should it be), so you should be getting this warning. As far as I know, there's no way to suppress it.

I would argue that this should not produce a warning, but that's the way that it is, and at least for now, you're going to just have to ignore it.

Comment: thank you for information. I knew it like component library!