# Angular-cli project cross platform build issue

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I've created experimental `angular-cli` project on Mac. Than I've moved it onto ubuntu and cant build:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

& start one:

```
$ ng serve
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (/project-path/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:51:63)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/project-path/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I confused, because it worked perfectly on Mac.

### Env details

```
$ npm -v
4.0.5
$ node -v
v7.4.0
$ ng -v
Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 7.4.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.0-rc0
@angular/cli: 1.5.5
@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.34
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.39
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.5
@schematics/angular: 0.1.9
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

I've found also answer *[npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226745/npm-warn-notsup-skipping-optional-dependency-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents)* it partly describes the messages, but it doesn't help me with my project running. (It can't be started any way).

Answer (score 1):

To make my project runnable on Ubuntu I need a missed file on Mac (it seems mac does not need one) - **.angular-cli.json**:

```
{
  "name": "angular4-in60-minutes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

After adding this file my project can be started correctly. But issue with warnings present anyway

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: The contents of the file you post here is not for an *angular-cli.json* file, it is for an *package.json* file. The warning you are getting is because your are on a non-Mac OS, and can safely be ignored. It happens on Windows, too. This answer has no good value when it is incorrect like this.

Comment: sorry, missed dot in file name, fixed. File name is **.angular-cli.json**