# Error in `npm install` in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react.js. I am trying to install react.js. In this regard I run `npm install -g create-react-app` and `create-react-app my-app`. Then I tried to run `npm install` command. But I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: Those are warnings. Not errors.

Comment: Can you please add the console logs as text

Comment: Thanks@SurajRao. There is no console logs.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, these are warnings (not errors) coming from libraries.

> ajv-keywords... requires ajv...

this is a bug and was [fixed 3 days ago](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/708).

> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.1.3...

for some reason NPM decided to skip it. However as [documentation points](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) out for optionalDependencies:

> The difference is that build failures do not cause installation to
>   fail.

.

> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform fsevent...

same as above. There's also [stackoverflow answer explaining it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40464936/4443323).

The last message of NPM is:

> up to date in 16.148s.

Which means everything is fine and installed properly.

EDIT:

as pointed out in a comment by @Suraj Rao

> fsevents is only required and used in OSX(darwin) environment.. You
>   will probably always get that warning in windows/linux

Comment: fsevents is only required and used in OSX(darwin) environment.. You will probably always get that warning in windows/linux

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz for your reply. How can I avoid that ? Thanks.

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks, I've included it in answer.

Comment: @abuabu you can't avoid that. The first warning will probably dissappear when new version of `ajv` will be released, and rest will always appear for windows/linux unless libraries change. Just don't worry about it (but it is confusing I admit).