# Yarn Node project fsevents linux incompatibiltiy

Tags: node.js, webpack, yarnpkg

I am getting an error (well, actually an info) when using `yarn` to build a Node project having Webpack as a `devDependency` in the `package.json`. I use Ubuntu 19.04:

```
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A new app.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "16.9.11",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "popper.js": "1.16.0",
        "react": "16.11.0",
        "react-dom": "16.11.0",
        "react-router-dom": "5.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "3.7.2",
        "webpack": "4.41.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "develop": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0 --config webpack.dev.config.js",
        "build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js"
    }
}
```

If I hit `yarn` again, the `info` does not reappear.

> node version: v13.1.0
>
> yarn version: 1.19.1

What is does this exactly mean? Are there missing parts? Can this be ignored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40464936/12251171).

Comment: @Bauke Thanks for the link. That was the answer.